# How to solder through-holes for quadcopter boards?

Tags: soldering, through-hole, quad-copter

[image: Here is an example of a board I want to solder]

Its a flight controller for multicopters. Should i stick the wires from the top or bottom, and should i solder the top side or bottom side? I searched on youtube, but there is no definitive way to do it, and no great camera angle for me to see how exactly its done, and many use pin headers isntead.

Should i tin or not? That kind of thing. I know it normally has to be a cone shaped, but not sure if this applies here.

And lastly, how to keep it holding all that as i solder? Its much harder i imagine than soldering onto a pad. Use helping hands on the wires?

Comment: So...you're asking how to solder? I feel like that's been asked before...

Comment: No, i know how, i do it all the time, and i can do this as well, but never tried and dont know whats the best way for this board.

Comment: You can also solder a connector on the board.

Answer (score 1):

You can stick the wires from both sides. Just think of which side do you have more space - or if they are equal - , to which side are the cables coming from. 
Also, pins are often used in order to access the board more easily but they require more space. If you are planning to change the wiring in the future, then pins are suggested.

Comment: Which side does the solder go, on the tip of the wire or near the silicone?

Comment: with sufficient power from a fine tip ( 60W ) heat should rapidly west up the middle,of the exposed wire protruding thru the hole thru the hole.  Adding proper  flux to the hole speeds up the process so that a sufficient but not excessive fillet of solder surrounds the wire on both sides of the hole.  Having the insulation close the hole and allowing some solder to wick under the insulation adds strength to the joint. The process should not take more than 5 seconds.

Comment: You need to do something like that https://youtu.be/oqV2xU1fee8 (at 2:17). There are many videos on youtube, just search "how to solder".

Comment: yea the videos dont show soldering wire to through holes, just breadboards or random boards.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 do i solder from the wire going in side or the opposite side? Like do i turn the board upside down, insert the wire and solder where it exits the hole??

Comment: Always from pigtail side as insulation near top hole edge would burn otherwise, then cut to 0.1" protrusion and  aim at garbage bin when doing it.

Comment: @Altoban I think the only answer is "it doesn't really matter", you can do whatever is most convenient. (e.g. if the wire is on the top, then soldering from the bottom means you won't burn the insulation, but soldering from the top means the wire can't fall out)